# What came first? Venom as the movie or as the song?

Tags: production, title, soundtrack, venom

What came first and which one was the inspiration to the second one? Or did both came continuously where Eminem cooperated with the movie creators for the purpose? Is there any article describing their cooperation in detail?

- [Venom](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1270797/) on IMDb, released 1st of October 2018 in the USA
- [Eminem - Venom](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8CdcCD5V-d8) on YouTube published 5th of October 2018 worldwide

Although the song came 4 days later, it's obvious October was a target month for both. Seems they cooperated together indeed. Where did the "Venom" idea came from?

Comment: The first sentence of the video's own description says *"Listen to Venom (Music from the Motion Picture), out now: ..."*. I would have expected that to be a big hint here.

Comment: Further, there are numerous references to the MCU on the *Venom* IMDb page. Given the lack of a question about what that is, I can't see how this question is remotely worth an upvote.

Comment: @Nij: I am aware of the description, thus the last 2-3 sentences of my question. However **that** is not an explanatory source I ask for. Those provided the 2 answers below I upvoted. If it is that obvious, why the answers came and were upvoted multiple-times?

Comment: If you don't know where Venom (the movie) came from, you did zero homework on this question.  As such, I proudly downvote.

Comment: @JohnnyBones: I didn't expect the unfriendly approach against the lower rep. people have been inherited from StackOverflow. If we all do the homework perfectly here, there would remain no content for any Q&A site, though. I try to do best to help newbies on SO, so I expect the same on the other SE site.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would point you to the Wikipedia page for this [song](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venom_(Eminem_song)) which reads:

> "Venom – Music from the Motion Picture", more commonly known as simply "Venom", is a song by American rapper Eminem, **written for the soundtrack of the 2018 film of the same name** and featured in his album Kamikaze.

(emphasis mine)

As far as which was *released* first, the same page has the following to say:

> On August 30, 2018, Eminem posted a 15-seconds teaser showing Venom's title with the "E" turning to the "backwards E", used as Eminem's emblem. Seven hours later, on August 31, 2018, Eminem's previously unannounced album Kamikaze was released, and "Venom" appeared as its final track. On September 21, 2018, the track was released as a separate digital single on streaming services

So I would say, rather than the movie inspiring the song or vice-versa, the producers of the film commissioned work from the artist (he was likely well paid for this - speculation on my part).

Logically, the song would have to be finished first to be included in the end credits of the film

Answer (score 8):

The song was written for the film.

> Eminem has released a teaser for a new song, seemingly set to be
>   featured on the soundtrack for the upcoming Marvel film Venom. Posted
>   to Instagram, the teaser shows the Venom title sequence shown in
>   previous trailers for the film, with the “E” eventually morphing into
>   Marshall Mathers’ signature backwards letter. Find that below.

[source](https://pitchfork.com/news/eminem-teases-venom-soundtrack-song/)

The Venom film was inspired by [a comic book character](https://www.marvel.com/comics/discover/713/venom-eddie-brock), not a song. The character was first introduced in 1988 ([The Amazing Spider-Man #299](https://www.marvel.com/comics/issue/6703/the_amazing_spider-man_1963_299)).

Comment: *Venom* was introduced in 1984, though I do see a $500 comic for 1963 that is likely a scam trying to fleece collectors for all they can.